# nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "brotli" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/brotli.conf:3 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Tags: next.js

I am deploying a next.js/ reactjs application on hostinger vps and the os is almalinux8 64bit with plesk.
I used command prompt to connect to the server and successfully hosted on ip address now when i am trying to transfer to the domain i am trying to configure nginx and installed all the packages but when i am trying to test the configuration "sudo nginx -t"  it is showing error
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "brotli" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/brotli.conf:3 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed.

i tried installing brotli and things but unable to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable brotli, the command line

```
# plesk bin nginx -e brotli
```

will do it. More information can be found on https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/12387812757143